# Unable to run tpm command of tungsten replicator

Tags: tungsten-replicator

I have cloned the latest tungsten installer and trying to run the tpm command. But its not recognizing as command. Please refer the snapshot below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ljca.png)

Please provide feedback.

Answer (score 0):

tpm is not in the path.  You need to explicitly state the path when you call it.  Using your example, you'd reference the directory you're in:

./tpm